# Unboxing wrapper classes to var-arg

Tags: java, arrays, oop, boxing

Why does this fail with a compilation failure?

```
class ZiggyTest {   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Integer[] i = {1,2,3,4};
        test(i);

    }   

    public static void test(int... s){
        for (int x : s){
            System.out.println(x);
        }   
    }
}
```

---

```
ZiggyTest.java:26: test(int...) in ZiggyTest cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer[])
        test(i);
        ^
1 error
```

What is the rule when it comes to unboxing wrapper arrays to var-args.

It does work if i declare the array as

```
int[] j = {1,2,3,4};
test(j);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because autoboxing can happen only from a primitive to it's wrapper (e.g. `int` to `Integer`), and not from array of a primitive to the array of the corresponding wrapper. Similar case with autounboxing.

e.g. if you define your test method as follows:

```
public static void test(int n) {} //<-- param n is of type int primitive
```

you could do something as follows:

```
Integer n = 1; // autoboxing happens here too
test(n); //this is a valid call because n is autounboxed
```

But, if you define your test method as follows:

```
public static void test(int[] n) {} //<-- param n is an array of int primitives
```

then something as follows will fail:

```
Integer[] ns = {1, 2}; // no autboxing here because we are dealing with array (just a syntactic sugar)
// Integer[] ns = new int[]{1, 2}; // something like this is not valid
test(ns); // this will fail
```

Answer (score 3):

An array of `int`s is not an array of `Integer`s. And the compiler tries to do that under the hood. So you can't do what you want.

You can either stick to one type of array, or use `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(..)` from commons-lang.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[].class != Integer[].class. 
int[].class = class [I
Integer[].class = class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

Thats is why it is complaining.

Comment: This is the class type of int array. i - stands for int and [- stands for one dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

What you are passing your method does not match what it is defined to expect. You set i as an array of `Integer` objects. Then you pass it to a method `test()`. The only method `test` you have defined is expecting an int which is a primitive type (**Integer != int**). You can quickly remedy it by changing the function definition of test to be:

```
public static void test(Integer[] s){
```